# Conversion of HTML string to HTML page of report Nessus security scanner

Tags: python, html, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When I run this command I get an HTML string:

```
report = client['SoftLayer_Network_Security_Scanner_Request'].getReport(id=19133434)
```

I wrote this data into `.html` file using Python. However, when I open the file through the browser some of the HTML features are not available. Could someone help me out with this?

Html code

```
u'<html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta><title>Nessus Scan Report</title><style type="text/css" media="all">\n\tUL.ulist {padding: 0 10px; line-height:25px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:0px;};\n\tLI.list {padding: 0 10px; line-height:25px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:0px; list-style: disc;}\n\tLI.list0 {padding: 0 10px; line-height:25px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:0px; list-style: disc; color:#357abd;}\n\tLI.list1 {padding: 0 10px; line-height:25px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:0px; l .....</html>
```

Comment: Show us the html string you get.

Comment: u'<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta><title>Nessus Scan Report</title><style type="text/css" media="all">\n\tUL.ulist {padding: 0 10px; line-height:25px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:0px;};\n\tLI.list  {padding: 0 10px; line-height:25px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:0px; list-style: disc;}\n\tLI.list0 {padding: 0 10px; line-height:25px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:0px; list-style: disc; color:#357abd;}\n\tLI.list1 {padding: 0 10px; line-height:25px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:0px; l  .....</html>'

Comment: @DixonAlmeida It would be better to edit that into your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this script:

```
"""
Get Report
Get the vulnerability report for a scan request.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Security_Scanner_Request/getReport

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import webbrowser
import SoftLayer

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# define the file's name
file = 'report.html'

# Create client
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
requestService = client['SoftLayer_Network_Security_Scanner_Request']

f = open(file, 'w')
try:
    report = requestService.getReport(id=19133434)
    f.write(report)
    f.close()
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(file)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to get report. faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

Let me know your results or if you continue having issues

**References:**

- [SoftLayer_Network_Security_Scanner_Request::getReport](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Security_Scanner_Request)

Comment: @Ruber_Cuellar how much time will be taken to generate report? and when i do get status. will i be getting generating report and then scan complete status?

Comment: It's immediately (few seconds to open the report), I'm not sure what you mean about when you get status, could you provide an example? You can only generate report from a scan complete